# What is wrong with my desert roses and how can I cure them?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, tropical

I got 7 desert rose plants about 2.5 months ago. They all now have something. I don't know. Leaf curls. some white stuff? (Might be rain residue/powdery mildew but I don't know which). Some spotty leaves. Some kind of... rot? on the flowers and buds. I've sprayed insecticide every few weeks or days. I don't know if that might not even be it. I'm in Indonesia. The temperature during the day is always around 30+ and I keep them in full sunlight. The soil is compost/black soil. I haven't gotten around to adding something more porous though I mean to soon. I water them every 1-2 days with half a cup of water direct to the soil around them mostly at night, sometimes early morning. Should I buy neem oil?

[image: Candik Ayu]

[image: Plant 2: Madeira]

[image: Plant 3: Sang rad sane/AC Milan?]

[image: Plant 4: White Rose]

Plant 1: Candik Ayu
Plant 2: Madeira
Plant 3: AC Milan/Sang rad sane? Purplish/red flowers. I think it's the latter but the labeling has faded I should be able to tell when it blooms. 
Plant 4: White Rose.